# flutter:how to save an image to a directory in the internal storage?

Tags: flutter, android-camera, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have got this Xfile path **("/data/user/0/com.example.cameraapp/cache/CAP4460198903632485844.jpg)**,
which has been returned by Camera.takePicture(this function is part of Camera flutter package).

my goal is to save  the picture in the returned path to a specific directory in the internal storage

how i could implement that ?

Comment: no need for any code , because i need the actual code that could solve my problem, and my problem is how i could take the image form the xFile and save it to another dir

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have a similar situation